# Bad question, bad answer but accepted

Tags: discussion

Is there anything that should be done more to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443809/using-val-to-return-the-value-not-working) question/answer on Stackoverflow?

The question is very weak and unclear, the answer (accepted by OP) is... well... <s>not a answer</s> a poor answer.

Close it? Delete it? Flag it to moderator attention?

Comment: Bad answers should be downvoted. If you suppose its a sock puppet then flag for mod attention.

Comment: Well, `you can use html()` *is* an answer. A bad answer, granted, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, can one use .html() in a input? or you mean that is the part where the answer is bad?

Comment: Chances are `#hello` is not an `<input>` (or does not exist at all), otherwise the questioner's code would work. Suggesting `html()` may be appropriate if the element is a `<div>` for instance. I deemed the answer bad because it does not explain the reasoning behind the proposed solution very well and operates on supposition instead of fact.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, well, the OP should have answered the comments of those who, like me, were trying to help. I ask here just to hear with the community what is best. So I know myself next time. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: @juergend, thank you for feedback. I did downvote both question and answer already yesterday. Just wasn't sure on what more could/should be done. So I asked here on Meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When judging the question don't worry about the answers.  Would you close this question if it didn't have any answers at all?

I would.  There isn't enough information to demonstrate the problem, so the cannot reproduce close reason would apply, as would closing as unclear what he's asking.  The question does need more information, but I don't see it as bad enough to need immediate deletion.  If the question ends up moving from on hold to closed and still hasn't been edited with code to reproduce it then perhaps it could be deleted.

As for judging the answer (which would be done separately) if you don't like it and don't think it's a good answer, you can downvote it.  It does appear to be an attempt to answer though, so flagging wouldn't be appropriate.

As for whether or not to cry over it; that's entirely up to you.  There are currently no site guidelines as to what questions should be cried over.

Comment: I did downvote it, already yesterday. The first comment there is mine, and I thought it would be answered by OP. Then I just checked it again now and saw it had a accepted answer... I agree with you. +1

Comment: Sevy, removed the cry part... I will keep it for my self.

Comment: +1 The last paragraph is gold! (But I agree too)

Comment: Sevy, thanks for feedback. I accept it as an answer and know better what to do next time.